# SQL Server grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I've got 'sales' table where I have `stor_id`, `ord_date`, and `quantity`.
The problem is to find the `stor_id` which has maximum `quantity` for that `ord_date`

I used below query

```
select sales.ord_date, sales.stor_id, sum(sales.qty)
from sales 
group by sales.ord_date, sales.stor_id
order by sales.ord_date desc
```

In the result i got for example, that on `2016-12-04` and `stor_id = 1` , the store has sold 35 books, and `stor_id = 2` shop has sold 20 books for that same day.

I'd like to take the maximum value (in this case `stor_id = 1` as it sold 35) of each group with the same date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below query of you are using sql server 2008 above

```
select * from
(
select 
ord_date, 
case 
  when s.tot_sales = max(s.tot_sales) over (partition by s.ord_date) 
  then s.stor_id 
  else NULL 
end as store_id, 
max(s.tot_sales) over (partition by s.ord_date) as maximum_sales 
from
(select distinct ord_date, stor_id, 
sum(qty) over (partition by ord_date, stor_id) as tot_sales
from sales 
)s
)s
where s.store_id is not NULL
```

**Working SQL fiddle:**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/179e1/8

For other versions of SQL server

```
select sales.* from 
    (
        select  ord_date, stor_id, 
        sum(qty) as tot_sales
        from sales 
        group by ord_date, stor_id
    )sales
    inner join
    (
        select 
        ord_date, 
        max(s.tot_sales) as maximum_sales 
        from
        (
            select  ord_date, stor_id, 
            sum(qty) as tot_sales
            from sales 
            group by ord_date, stor_id
        )s
        group by ord_date 
    )s  
    on sales.ord_date=s.ord_date and sales.tot_sales=s.maximum_sales
```

**Working sql fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/179e1/9

Comment: Have you heard of common table expressions?  Try cleaning this guy up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method is to use window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.ord_date, s.stor_id, sum(s.qty) as sumqty,
             row_number() over (partition by s.ord_date order by sum(s.qty) desc) as seqnum
      from sales s
      group by s.ord_date, s.stor_id
    ) s
where seqnum = 1
order by s.ord_date desc;
```

Note that in the event of ties, this returns one store.  If you want all of them, use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to find the `store_id` which has maximum quantity for that `ord_date`. To get this, we need to follow these step.

- Find Summation of quantity for every `ord_date` and `stor_id` group

  ```
  -- lets think (for few seconds) we store the result in CTE_Total_Sales_Per_Day table
  SELECT 
     stor_id,
     ord_date,
     SUM(qty) AS total_quantity
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY ord_date, stor_id
  ```
- Find maximum quantity of that `ord_date`

  ```
  -- lets think (for few seconds) we store the result in CTE_Maximum_Sales_Per_Day table
  SELECT 
     ord_date,
     MAX(total_quantity) AS max_quantity
  FROM CTE_Total_Sales_Per_Day 
  GROUP BY ord_date
  ```
- Join these two tables by `ord_date` and `quantity`

  ```
  SELECT 
     CTSPD.* 
  FROM CTE_Total_Sales_Per_Day CTSPD
  INNER JOIN CTE_Maximum_Sales_Per_Day CMSPD
   ON CTSPD.ord_date = CMSPD.ord_date
     AND CTSPD.max_quantity = CMSPD.total_quantity
  ```

**Here goes the final query**

```
;WITH CTE_Total_Sales_Per_Day (stor_id, ord_date, total_quantity)
AS
(
    SELECT stor_id, ord_date, SUM(qty) AS total_quantity FROM Sales
    GROUP BY ord_date, stor_id
)
,CTE_Maximum_Sales_Per_Day(ord_date, max_quantity)
AS
(
   SELECT ord_date, MAX(total_quantity) AS max_quantity
   FROM CTE_Total_Sales_Per_Day
   GROUP BY ord_date
)
,CTE_Maximum_Sales_Store_Id_Per_Day (stor_id, ord_date, total_quantity)
AS
(
    SELECT 
       CTSPD.* 
    FROM CTE_Total_Sales_Per_Day CTSPD
    INNER JOIN CTE_Maximum_Sales_Per_Day CMSPD
     ON CTSPD.ord_date = CMSPD.ord_date
       AND CTSPD.max_quantity = CMSPD.total_quantity
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_Maximum_Sales_Store_Id_Per_Day
```

At last, here i use **WITH Common Table Expression**. To learn about this, you can take a look at here [WITH Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)